# Splitting Excel workbook with 50 Sheets into CSV files IN R

Tags: r, excel

I am a very basic R user and not into loops or advanced R. Challenge I am facing with an Excel Workbook with 50 worksheets and each worksheet is comprising of 1 Million rows. Loading into R this huge workbook of appx 5GB is not getting possible. I am looking forward for a fast method in R to get this workbook split into multiple CSVs of a single consolidated one

Tried to search lot of solutions and system is not responding for hours.

Please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

What about a function like this?

```
library(readxl)

csv_saver <- function(sheet_number){
  
  csv <- read_xlsx(path = "yr_file_name.xlsx", sheet = sheet_number)
  write.csv(csv, file = paste0("sheet_",sheet_number,".csv"))
  
}

lapply(1:50, csv_saver)
```

This reads in the sheet number specified by the variable `sheet_number` as a dataframe and then writes the dataframe out as csv file. You then apply that function to the vector of all the numbers between 1 and 50

Comment: This gives you fifty different csv files. If you try to load them all into R and then write  them all as a huge csv file you'll probably still encounter the memory problems you described... You could also just read in individual sheets as dataframes as you need them using the `sheet` argument in `read_xlsx()`

Comment: Thanks Russ!!! It's working and I am able to split the huge excel into multiple CSVs from which I am able to extract desired results. Just an input required for every new CSV , first data line becomes the header. Can the header be placed on all CSvs while splitting

Comment: You mean like make the first row the column names? You could try changing the `header=` argument, you can run this in R to see the help page: `?read.csv()`             Or do you mean make all the values in the first row the csv's file name?